# Retrieve array of dictionary from Firebase & Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I have a json database on firebase and trying to get them and put into local array of dictionaries.

My json model on Firebase

[image]

My struct model is also like below

```
struct Places {
var type:String!
var country:String!
var name:String!
var image:String!
var coords:[Coords]!


init(type: String, country: String, name: String, image: String, coords: [Coords]) {
    self.type = type
    self.country = country
    self.name = name
    self.image = image
    self.coords = coords
}

init(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {

    let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! [String:Any]

    type = snapshotValue["type"] as! String
    country = snapshotValue["country"] as! String
    name = snapshotValue["name"] as! String
    image = snapshotValue["image"] as! String
    coords = snapshotValue["coords"] as! [Coords]!
}
```

}

And also [Coords] struct model like below:

```
struct Coords {

var latStart:String!
var latEnd:String!
var lonStart:String!
var lonEnd:String!

init(latStart: String, latEnd: String, lonStart: String, lonEnd: String) {
    self.latStart = latStart
    self.latEnd = latEnd
    self.lonStart = lonStart
    self.lonEnd = lonEnd
}
```

}

And I am trying to get and put json data by below code:

```
placesRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            if !snapshot.exists() {
                print("data not exist")
                return
            }

                var plc: [Places] = []

                for eachPlace in (snapshot.children){
                    let place = Places(snapshot: eachPlace as! FIRDataSnapshot)

                    plc.append(place)
                }

            self.allPlaces = plc
```

The problem is that I can get the array of dictionary except coords dictionary inside array of dictionary. [Coords] dictionary seems null and I would like to know what the problem is. Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Because `snapshotValue["coords"] as! [Coords]!` are not `Coords` yet.  They are just dictionaries. You have to go through each dictionary in `snapshotValue[“coords”]` and init a `Coords` object, then when you’re finished group them all into an array and assign it to `self.coords` of the `Places` struct.  The `map` function is really convenient for this.

**Example:**

I would change the `Coords` init function to something like:

```
init(dictionary: [String : AnyObject]) {
    self.latStart = dictionary["lat1"] as? String
    //...
    //...
}
```

Then in `Places` init use something like:

```
coords = (snapshotValue["coords"] as? [[String : AnyObject]])?.map({ Coord(dictionary: $0) })
```

I didn't test this and making some assumptions here, but you should be able to make something similar work.

Comment: Can you add an example of using the `map` function in this context?

Comment: @ForestKunecke I added an untested example.

Comment: It didn't give error anymore but still nil when I print allPlaces array; Places(type: City, country: US, name: New York City, image: newyorkcity, coords: nil)]

Comment: It will likely be nil if `snapshotValue["coords"]` is not actually type `[[String : AnyObject]]` like in my example.  I didn't test this, so you have to make sure you have the right types yourself.

Comment: Thats should be accepted solution. I had the same problem and it helped me.